# A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

> Additional information: 'No matching constructor found on type
>   'GameDealModule.View.TossBoardView'.  You can use the Arguments or
>   FactoryMethod directives to construct this type. 'Line number '20' and
>   line position '22'.
>
> No default constructor found for type
>   'GameDealModule.View.TossBoardView'.  You can use the Arguments or
>   FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.

I am using separate view inside the popup control in wpf using mvvm.

Comment: public HeaderView(HeaderViewModel headerViewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();          

                this.DataContext = headerViewModel;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

Comment: Heed the error message. It says clearly that there is no default constructor. Create a default constructor then. Or don't try to invoke the default constructor.